# How to get record in between time range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to fetch some result from table depending on time range so i did

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where convert(varchar(10),CountryTime,108) between '15:00' and '16:00'
```

CountryTime- is of varchar type..
but iam not getting corect output plz suggets..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use varchar(5) instead of varchar(8)

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
  where convert(varchar(5),CountryTime,108) between '15:00' and '16:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
where DATEPART(HOUR, CountryTime) IN (15, 16)
```